# 2005 Crown Victoria Police Interceptor showing codes P0053, P0054, P0059 and P0060

Tags: ford, o2-sensor, crown-victoria

I have replaced all 4 oxygen sensors and OBD II code still shows codes P0053, 54, 59, and 60. What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

The O2 sensors have 2 white and 2 black wires. Exactly which red/yellow wire are you referring to?

Comment: it might be a bad pcm if you performed all of those tests. I have the same problem in a 2011 crown Vic P7B. I can’t even find a replacement computer except for on flagshipone.com but they’d appear to be a scam

Answer (score 5):

Check fuse 21 in the under hood fuse box. If the fuse is OK at one of the o2 sensors check for power on the red/yellow wire. If you have no power at the o2 sensor I'm afraid your going to be looking for a short to ground. Which would involve tracing the wiring harness and visually inspecting for rub through or broken wiring.

Comment: I think you are spot on with the fuse aspect here. Most likely the case since both sides are having a heater issue. Could *also* be a ground short. Fuses usually blow for a reason.

Answer (score 4):

The Red/Yellow wire is in the harness, not on the O2 sensor.

It's can only be something that effects all 4 sensors. The ground is provided individually for each sensor by the PCM so it can't be on the ground side.

Power is provided by Fuse 21, but that also powers the EVAP canister vent valve so  if that fuse was blown it would also set an EVAP code, but you defiantly have a problem on the power side of the harness. Shortly after the Red/Yellow wire leaves the Fuse block it splits off from the EVAP circuit and runs down near the right side headlamp, along the right inner fender (under the finder skirt if I remember correctly).

Trace that wire from the fuse box to the O2 sensors, you will likely find a damaged harness along the lower right fender area. You will have to get to it from the bottom of the car. I have had at least two different Crown Vics with damage in the same area. I believe it's a common failure.

Comment: I don't see too many crown vics anymore but fender areas on american cars tend to be problem areas.

Answer (score 2):

After replacing the sensors- did you clear the codes and drive the car on the highway for a while so that the car computer can re-read the cars activity codes?  After finding the codes and performing repair, you should clear codes before trying to get another code reading.  Try clearing your codes first.  No promises here- but this maybe just what you need.

Comment: Yes, I cleared the codes and drove the car about 65 miles before the check engine light came back on. I pulled off the highway immediately and checked the codes, and they were the same 4 codes again.

Comment: I've also checked for shorted or broken wiring to the sensors, checked the fuse, hooked up a multimeter to both sides of the wiring connectors, and checked the sensors for correct resistance at full operating temperature.